# Blueimp file upload issues

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-file-upload

when i run my app, fileupload function shows error

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fileupload'**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();

    $('#fileupload').fileupload({

    **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fileupload'**
        url: '/create_p',
        add: function (e, data) {
                        $('#upload').append('<p class="upl">Uploading...please wait</p>');
                        data.submit();
                    },
        success: function (r) {
                $('#upload').remove();  
                //alert(r["id"]) ;
        $('#id_p').attr('value',r["id"]);
                }
    });
    });
```

Comment: Make sure that _fileupload_ plugin is loaded.

Comment: These are the error, that i got. when i remove this from script, my rails application works

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileupload' of undefined application-35a0cf7e730ad3cc84a416e556c1742d.js:292
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fileupload' application-35a0cf7e730ad3cc84a416e556c1742d.js:282

Comment: Any updates on that issue? I am struggling with the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Please check element where u called fileupload, and fileupload library dependency should be added **before** call the fileupload function.